# TYPO3 Extbase - Paginate through a large table (100000 records)

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a fairly large table with about 100000 records. If I don't set the limit in the repository

Repository:

```
public function paginateRequest() {

$query = $this->createQuery();
$result = $query->setLimit(1000)->execute();
//$result = $query->execute();
return $result;

}

/**
 * action list
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction() {

$this->view->assign('records', $this->leiRepository->paginateRequest());

//$this->view->assign('records', $this->leiRepository->findAll());

}
```

... the query and the page breaks although I'm using f:widget.paginate . As per the docs https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Widget/PaginateViewHelper.html I was hoping that I can render only the itemsPerPage and 'parginate' through the records ...

List.hmtl

```
<f:if condition="{records}">
<f:widget.paginate objects="{records}" as="paginatedRecords" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 100, insertAbove: 0, insertBelow: 1, maximumNumberOfLinks: 10}">                     
    <f:for each="{paginatedRecords}" as="record">
        <tr>
            <td><f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" arguments="{record:record}"> {record.name}</f:link.action></td>
            <td><f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" arguments="{record:record}"> {record.lei}</f:link.action></td>
        </tr>
    </f:for>
</f:widget.paginate>
```

Model:

class Lei extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

```
...
/**
 * abc
 *
 * @lazy
 * @var string
 */
protected $abc = '';
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use in TYPO3 9.5. The next function in repository:

```
public function paginated($page = 1, $size = 9){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $begin = ($page-1) * $size;
    $query->setOffset($begin);
    $query->setLimit($size);
    return $query->execute();
}
```

And in the controller I am using arguments as parameter to send the page to load in a Rest action.

```
public function listRestAction()
{

    $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
    $totalElements = $this->repository->total();
    $pages = ceil($totalElements/9);
    $next_page = '';
    $prev_page = '';
    #GET Page to load
    if($arguments['page'] AND $arguments['page'] != ''){
        $page_to_load = $arguments['page'];
    } else {
        $page_to_load = 1; 
    }
    #Configuration of pagination
    if($page_to_load == $pages){
        $prev = $page_to_load - 1;
        $prev_page = "http://example.com/rest/news/page/$prev";
    } elseif($page_to_load == 1){
        $next = $page_to_load + 1;
        $next_page = "http://example.com/rest/news/page/$next";
    } else {
        $prev = $page_to_load - 1;
        $prev_page = "http://example.com/rest/news/page/$prev";
        $next = $page_to_load + 1;
        $next_page = "http://example.com/rest/news/page/$next";
    }

    $jsonPreparedElements = array();
    $jsonPreparedElements['info']['count'] = $totalElements;        
    $jsonPreparedElements['info']['pages'] = $pages;
    $jsonPreparedElements['info']['next'] = $next_page;
    $jsonPreparedElements['info']['prev'] = $prev_page;
    $result = $this->repository->paginated($page_to_load);
    $collection_parsed_results = array();
    foreach ($result as $news) {
        array_push($collection_parsed_results, $news->parsedArray());
    }
    $jsonPreparedElements['results'] = $collection_parsed_results;
    $this->view->assign('value', $jsonPreparedElements);
}
```

The result of this, is a JSON like this:

```
{
"info": {
    "count": 25,
    "pages": 3,
    "next": "",
    "prev": "http://example.com/rest/news/page/2"
},
"results": [
    { ....}
] }
```

Answer (score 0):

How large / complex are the objects you want to paginate through? If they have subobjects that you dont need in the list view, add @lazy annotation to those relations inside the model.

Due to this large amount of records, you should keep them as simple as possible in the list view. You can try to only give the result as array to the list view using `$this->leiRepository->findAll()->toArray()` or return only the raw result from your repository by adding true to execute(true).

You can also create an array of list items yourself in a foreach in the controller and only add the properties you really need inside the list.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I tried the @lazy load, ->toArray() and execute(true) ... but it still breaks. When you ask for 'how large/complex the objects should be?' ... do you mean how many records I want to display in the list view per pagination tab? I hope at least 100 ... And by subobjects?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the performance, just use the default findAll()-Method.

The built-in defaultQuerySettings in \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository set their offset and limit based on the Pagination widget, if not set otherwise.

If the performance issue persists, you may have to consider writing a custom query for your database request, that only requests the data your view actually displays. The process is described in the documentation:  https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html